# The Best™ class

Tags: kotlin

Have you ever wanted to get just not *one* "best" element from a list, but *all* of them, or a *random* element of the best ones? That's what the Best class is here for. Opinion-based? Definitely not!

Features:

- Should work with any kind of element.
- Should always keep track of the best elements seen so far.
- Should be able to get a list of all best elements
- Should be able to get a single best element

I thought about supporting both `Comparator<T>` and `(T) -> Double`, but realized that I have a use-case for actually finding out the actual *value* as well (for an implementation of Alpha-Beta pruning in Minmax algorithm). I thought that `(T) -> Double` option is more flexible in the long run (feel free to convince me about otherwise).

#### Code

The code is written for multi-platform Kotlin projects. It should be able to compile to both JVM, JavaScript, and Kotlin Native.

```
class Best<T>(private val valueFunction: (T) -> Double) {

    private var bestValue: Double = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY
    private var bestElements: MutableList<T> = mutableListOf()

    fun next(element: T) {
        val value = valueFunction(element)
        if (value > bestValue) {
            bestValue = value
            bestElements = mutableListOf(element)
        } else if (value >= bestValue) {
            bestElements.add(element)
        }
    }

    fun randomBest(): T = bestElements.random()
    fun getBest(): List<T> = bestElements.toList()
    fun firstBest(): T = bestElements.first()
    fun isBest(element: T): Boolean = bestElements.contains(element)
    fun getBestValue(): Double = bestValue

}
```

#### Tests

```
class BestTest {

    private fun createBest(): Best<String> {
        val best = Best<String> { it.length.toDouble() }
        best.next("hi")
        best.next("hello")
        best.next("")
        best.next("world")
        return best
    }

    @Test
    fun empty() {
        val emptyBest = Best<Double> { it }
        assert(emptyBest.getBest().isEmpty())
        assertThrows<NoSuchElementException> { emptyBest.randomBest() }
        assertThrows<NoSuchElementException> { emptyBest.firstBest() }
        assertFalse(emptyBest.isBest(4.2))
    }

    @Test
    fun random() {
        val randomBest = createBest().randomBest()
        assertTrue(randomBest == "hello" || randomBest == "world")
    }

    @Test
    fun bestList() {
        val allBest = createBest().getBest()
        assertEquals(listOf("hello", "world"), allBest)
    }

    @Test
    fun firstBest() {
        assertEquals("hello", createBest().firstBest())
    }

    @Test
    fun isBest() {
        val best = createBest()
        assertFalse(best.isBest(""))
        assertFalse(best.isBest("hi"))
        assertFalse(best.isBest("something random that was never added"))
        assertTrue(best.isBest("hello"))
        assertTrue(best.isBest("world"))
    }

}
```

#### Questions

- Does this class seem useful? (Is it as useful as the name sounds?)
- Would this class benefit from implementing Kotlin's `Collection` interface?
- Any improvement suggestions that you can think of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the things I really like about Kotlin is how the source code for existing functions in the `stdlib` are readily available and can be leveraged to quickly create very efficient functions that are similar to existing ones.

In your particular case I suggest taking a look at [`max`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max.html), [`maxBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-by.html), and [`maxWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-with.html). We can create our own extension functions that instead of returning a single "max" element returns a `List` of them. e.g. `maxElements`, `maxElementsBy`, and `maxElementsWith`.

For this example we only need a `maxElementsWith` function which takes a `Comparator` (based on [`maxWith` source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L1688-L1700)):

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.maxElementsWith(comparator: Comparator<in T>): List<T> {
    val iterator = iterator()
    if (!iterator.hasNext()) return emptyList()
    var max = iterator.next()
    var maxElements = mutableListOf(max)
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        val e = iterator.next()
        when (comparator.compare(e, max).sign) {
            1 -> {
                max = e
                maxElements = mutableListOf(max)
            }
            0 -> maxElements.add(e)
        }
    }
    return maxElements
}
```

You can then use `maxElementsWith` to find a single "best" (max) value, a list of them, a random one, etc.

If you need the weight of the best/max values then you could first map your list of items to a list of pairs of the weight to the item. Pairs often get a bit tricky to read so you might even create a `WeightedValue` `data class` to improve readability:

Examples:

```
val elements = listOf("hi", "hello", "", "world")

val bestElements = elements.maxElementsWith(compareBy(String::length))
println(bestElements)
// [hello, world]

println(bestElements.random())
// ${either hello or world}

val newBestElements = bestElements.plus("supercalifragilisticexpialidocious")
    .maxElementsWith(compareBy(String::length))
println(newBestElements)
// [supercalifragilisticexpialidocious]

println(
    elements.map { it.length to it }
        .maxElementsWith(compareBy { it.first })
        .first()
        .first
)
// 5

data class WeightedValue<out T, out W>(val weight: W, val value: T)

fun <T, W> Iterable<T>.withWeight(weigher: (T) -> W): List<WeightedValue<T, W>> {
    return map { WeightedValue(weigher(it), it) }
}

println(
    elements.withWeight { it.length.toDouble() }
        .maxElementsWith(compareBy { it.weight })
        .first()
        .weight
)
// 5.0
```

[Kotlin Playground Link](https://pl.kotl.in/N9D29SNCp)

Answer (score 5):

I hate the name, but don't have a better one so I'll leave that for another answer.

Here's what I do have though: why not make it *more* generic?

I'm looking at this function:

```
fun next(element: T) {
    val value = valueFunction(element)
    if (value > bestValue) {
        bestValue = value
        bestElements = mutableListOf(element)
    } else if (value >= bestValue) {
        bestElements.add(element)
    }
}
```

Why not make a `isBetterThanFunction: (T, T) -> Boolean` and `isEqualToFunction: (T, T) -> Boolean`. Then, you can support a wider array of items, and you don't need `valueFunction`.

```
class Best<T>(private val isBetterThanFunction: (T, T) -> Boolean, private val isEqualToFunction: (T, T) -> Boolean) {

    private var bestValue: ...
    private var bestElements: MutableList<T> = mutableListOf()

    fun next(element: T) {
        if (isBetterThanFunction(element, bestValue)) {
            bestValue = element
            bestElements = mutableListOf(element)
        } else if (isEqualToFunction(element, bestValue)) {
            bestElements.add(element)
        }
    }

    fun randomBest(): T = bestElements.random()
    fun getBest(): List<T> = bestElements.toList()
    fun firstBest(): T = bestElements.first()
    fun isBest(element: T): Boolean = bestElements.contains(element)
    fun getBestValue(): Double = bestValue

}
```

To me, it makes things more clear. I'm no longer inferring what you mean with `(T) -> Double`. How is that weighted? Well, now *I* make that decision.

Why does this matter? What if I defined `best` as "shortest"? With your version, I have to get clever about it and probably negate the value or something. With this version, *I* pick how that works.

Comment: I imagine there would be quite a bit of duplicated code in a lot of cases between the `isBetterThan` and `isEqualTo`. Also, as I wrote in the question, I have a use-case for getting the actual value as well. But you are right that I had to negate the value in my minimax implementation, which is indeed a problem I would like to avoid.

Comment: Subclass and change the implementation there.

Comment: What's wrong with the name? :)

Comment: @SimonForsberg I just don't like it, but I don't have an alternative so take that with a grain of salt lol

Answer (score 5):

The question whether to use `(T) -> Double` or `Comparator<T>` probably depends on your use case. If you have a scenario where you explicitly know, that your objects can always be mapped to a double, then it's fine to use `(T) -> Double`.

On the other hand, once you have such a weighting function, then it's trivial to create a `Comparator` based on that. And (my gut says - I haven't researched it) the reverse (creating a weighting function out of a `Comparator`) may not be possible. That means a version using a `Comparator` would be more flexible.

> Does this class seem useful? (Is it as useful as the name sounds?)

I'm sure there is a scenario where this could be used, but I don't like the name either. Maybe something like `BestWeightHolder`?

> Would this class benefit from implementing Kotlin's Collection interface?

IMO, no, not directly. That actually touches one of my criticisms I have: You have several "utility" methods (`randomBest`, `firstBest` and possibly `contains`) which don't seem to fit into the purpose of the class IMO, especially since they can just as well be executed on the list returned by `toList`.

I think you should drop those methods and replace `toList` with an `asCollection` method, which returns not a copy of the list of best items, but a direct reference of your internal list limited to the `Collection` interface (or if you want to make sure it is not cast back to a `MutableList` and modified, an instance of a thin wrapper class that implements `Collection`). The user then can use `first()`, `random()`, `contains()`and more on that.

> Any improvement suggestions that you can think of

I'm not a big fan of the method name `next`. Methods of that name usually indicate a supplying method (as in an `Iterator`, for example). I'd suggest `add` or (following Java's `Integer/Long/DoubleSummaryStatistics` classes which have a similar function and which implement `Consumer<T>`) `accept`.

One tiny thing:

> ```
> } else if (value >= bestValue) {
> ```

should use `==` instead of `>=`.

And finally, personally, following Kotlin's pattern, I would consider implementing this as an immutable class.

Comment: What's wrong with the name? :)

Comment: @SimonForsberg It's not the best :)

Answer (score 1):

What I see here is either:

- Trying to sort list based on a value and getting item (or items) from top of the list. In that case you can use comparator and take stuff from top of that list. I don't see argument in being able to access actual "value". I see it as adding more responsibilities to the class.
- Trying to filter out and cache some results. In that case I see this as sequence of objects (similar to for example Rx programming) and in that case a simple .filter {} lambda would be enough for me while providing me with more flexibility with how to filter, aggregate data and what to do with them after.

Overall I don't find this class useful unless for something very specific.

Comment: Sorting a list and then get one item from that list is a O(n log n) operation, while looping through the list once to get the highest value(s) is a O(n) operation and therefore much more effective. I don't see how this class is related to filtering out and caching results - to do that filtering I would have to loop through the list twice, once to find the maximum value and then once to do the filtering. This class only loops once.

Comment: I am talking about semantic value and that's what I semantically see there. We can also talk about effectivity and yes sorting big list would be ineffective. To filter stuff above some threshold (that's what I understand you are doing) you need only one loop, which can work for both cases and speed up them significantly. If you want to focus about efficiency, please specify that ;)

Comment: An example I gave in the question is the Alpha-Beta pruning algorithm, which while not necessarily creates a big list it takes a lot of time for each element to calculate the value, so I'd really like to avoid looping over the list any more than once. I am filtering stuff based on *the biggest value found so far*, not based on any pre-known fixed value, therefore a regular `.filter` wouldn't work unless you accept side-effects from the call to `.filter`, which IMO is bad practice.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I wasn't talking literally only about `filter` (should have phrased better), but also about other lambdas. You could still implement that using `filter` and nested lambda without side effects, but that would be a bit clunky and weird way of using it. This sounds more like `maxBy` as was mentioned earlier already by mfulton26.

Comment: Exactly, this is `maxBy` with the difference that I also want the possibility of returning a collection of *all* the max's and not just one. mfulton26's suggestion of using an extension function is what I will go with. Thank you for your feedback :)

Comment: You are welcome, thank you for discussion!